# $http.get() with Basic Auth is failing at OPTIONS call in AngularJS, IONIC

Tags: javascript, http, ionic-framework, get, cors

I am making a call from ionic app with following code:-

```js
var req={
   method: "GET",
   url: "<Some URL>",
   headers:{
   "Authorization": "Basic YjEyMDMwOmJjb25lQDEyMw=="
   }
  }
  $http(req).then(function success(){
   alert("Yesss");
  },function failure(a,b,c){
   alert("nahhh");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Below image shows failure in OPTIONS call.

[Failing call in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY4e1.png)

Whereas same call works fine from SAPUI5 which takes care of CORS internally with oModel.Read() operation.
Below is the successful call screenshot:-

[Passing call in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kplD8.png)

What am i doing wrong? or is it even possible to make CORS based call from AngularJS app?

edit1:

I just noticed, if i give header- Authorization, rest of the headers are ignored, and accept goes with text/plain... etc
But if authorization header is not there, it takes Accept and other params, but since my service is Basic auth based, it would need this header, now how do i crack this?

edit2:
I tried same thing in $.get ajax call, and noticed, if i pass "Authorization" header or any other random header like "doijwoid" no other headers are shown in request header calls, but when i omit this header other headers like "Accept" works as written in code.

```js
$.get({url:"<SRV URL>",headers:{"Accept":"application/json"}}, function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

[Ajax call without authorization header][3]

[Call with Authorization header and Accept as well, but accept header not taken][4]

Comment: From what I understand, you can make CORS based calls from javascript(be it angular or any other framework), provided the server side configurations for allowing CORS is done.

Comment: Yes, maybe i need to skip OPTIONS call as when i try with $http.JSONP, it returns 200OK and no OPTIONS call is made, but my code goes into error function instead of success.

Comment: Your request headers look completely different and seem to be missing the authorisation field, has additional fields called 'access-control-request-headers' instead with value "authorisation", so there is something wrong with the code, but I am not familiar enough with ionic framework to say exactly what.

Comment: From what I see you have not added an "Accept" type "application/json" and requesting with "text/html.....". Hence the request might be preflighted because the server can only respond with "application/json" or whatever it's configured with. Try adding "Accept: applcation/json" in your header

Comment: If i give Authorization header, rest of the headers are gone, but ignoring Authorization, it takes other headers.

Comment: "Whereas same call works fine from SAPUI5" — Your screenshot shows that the two requests are going to different servers. Since CORS requires a correct response to the OPTIONS request it is possible that either one request is a same origin request and not cross origin at all or that one of the servers is configured to respond to OPTIONS requests with permissions.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar — That's because one of the requests is a pre-flight OPTIONS request and the other is a GET request. If the OPTIONS request got a response giving the browser permission to make the GET request then it might make the same GET request (albeit to a different server)

Comment: @rohitaneja — If you use jsonp then you skip the OPTIONS request for a variety of reasons, but one of them is that you won't be sending the `Authorization` you are trying to explicitly send in your code.

Comment: Agreed with @ArathiSreekumar as former one skips CORS call and directly have GET call.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, and with jsonp as i am not sending Authorization, it throws an error. So now, given i want to make $http.get but with authorization header, issue is call doesn't succeed and fails with 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: @rohitaneja — That's because the server isn't properly responding to the preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, i'll check this part on server side, but if you would be able to explain how its working in Open UI5, basically how its skipping and making get call, can't same thing be replicated with $http API's

Comment: Aside from the guess I made in my earlier comment. No, I can't. I can't see the code for it so I don't know what it is doing.

Comment: Are you trying on device or browser? Is your browser giving preflight error?